# Rails Tutorial Chapter 8: How does is_logged_in? pass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

OK, so I finished the chapter, and all code works fine. But I'm confused about one bit. In sessions_helper_test, I setup the remember token cookies directly. The test against is_logged_in? passes, even though the is_logged_in? checks the session only.

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
    remember(@user)
  end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all
  include ApplicationHelper

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...

  def is_logged_in?
    !session[:user_id].nil?
  end
  ...
end


module SessionsHelper

  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Remember user in persistent session
  def remember(user)
    user.remember  
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
  end
  ...
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end
  ...
end
```

Can anyone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the code I understood 'remember(@user)' is creating the cookies, which is used by the 'current_user' method to return the user when session is null.

```
assert_equal @user, current_user
```

From the book, here is the code for current_user:

```
module SessionsHelper
  .
  .
  .
  # Returns the user corresponding to the remember token cookie.
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

From the above code I guess, when User passed the Authentication using the remember_token cookies, "log_in" method is called which is setting up the "session[:user_id]"

Comment: Man! I have no idea how I missed this. Thanks :)